# Config file not found when launching jar from cmd line

Tags: java, command-line, classpath, logback

I can't determine how to add a config file to my classpath. I have the following directory structure:

```
dir
 |-config
      |-logback.xml
 |-lib
 |-logs     
 |-myapp.jar
```

When I try to run this jar from the command line as follows:

`java -cp myapp.jar;config/logback.xml;lib/*; my.app.Main`

the `logback.xml` file is not found. However, if I move the logback file up to the main directory (i.e. dir), and execute the jar with:
`java -cp myapp.jar;logback.xml;lib/*; my.app.Main` then it is found.

So why is it only found if it resides at the same level as the main jar?

Comment: How are you loading/accessing the file? Code snippet..

Comment: Try `java -cp myapp.jar;config;lib/*; my.app.Main`.

Comment: @saka1029 That works. I don't understand why `config/*` or `config/logback.xml` would not work though.

Comment: You must specify jar file or **directory** as class path. Not **file**